# Setting backgroundView of UITableView cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm setting the background of a UITableViewCell and for whatever reason it will not appear.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
cell.textLabel.text = [[_comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] text];
((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble.png"];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];

return cell;
```

Everything **but** the `cell.backgroundView` works. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't have type casted it.

Solution was to set a `UIImageView` image and then set it directly.

```
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
(bgView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble.png"];
cell.backgroundView = bgView;
[bgView release];
```